# Create subplots on the same page

Tags: python

How do I subplots multiple graphs? so it will look like the picture.
[the image is how the plots should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpa2G.png)
Im able to plot individule but i cant figure out

```
A = 1  # Wave amplitude in meters
T = 10  # Time Period in secs
pi = 3.14  # Value of pi
n_w = 10 # Number of waves
wavelength = 156  # Wavelength in meters


k = (2 * pi) / wavelength
w = (2 * pi) / T

def wave_elevation(x,t):
    return A * np.cos((k * x) - (w * t))

t_list = np.array([0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0])*T

for t in t_list:
    wave_ele_Val = []
    for i in np.linspace(0,wavelength*n_w,1560):
        wave_ele_Val.append(wave_elevation(i,t))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,wavelength*n_w,1560),wave_ele_Val,'r')
    plt.title("Wave Elevation-Space Variations @ " + str(t) + "* Time Periods")
    plt.xlabel("x (m)")
    plt.ylabel("\u03B7")
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring figures outside loop.

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = 1  # Wave amplitude in meters
T = 10  # Time Period in secs
pi = 3.14  # Value of pi
n_w = 10 # Number of waves
wavelength = 156  # Wavelength in meters

k = (2 * pi) / wavelength
w = (2 * pi) / T

def wave_elevation(x,t):
    return A * np.cos((k * x) - (w * t))

x_list = np.array([0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0])*wavelength
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(x_list), figsize=(15, 5))
for i, x in enumerate(x_list):
    wave_ele_Val = []
    for j in np.linspace(0,T*n_w,1000):
        wave_ele_Val.append(wave_elevation(x, j))
    
    ax[i].plot(np.linspace(0,T*n_w,1000),wave_ele_Val)
    ax[i].grid()
plt.show()
```

all the configuration is in the [link](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)

Comment: It didn't work. Am i suppose to get rid of the loop first?

Comment: The first graph was correct but the other 4 are not correct. They are oscillating to much.

Comment: Your edit worked for part-a but when i did part-b it didn't work. I used the same code from part-a but changed the values. How do i do part-b?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify how many subplots you want:

`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, *, sharex=False, sharey=False, squeeze=True, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None, **fig_kw)`

In your case this would be plt.subplots(5)

The plt.plot() needs to be changed to ax[i].plot(x,y)
Where i is your number of subplot.

Also shift the plt.show() outside of the loop, so it is called at the end and not in between.

This is one example, how you can do it:

```
x_list = np.array([0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0])*wavelength
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, figsize=(15, 5))

for j,x in enumerate(x_list):
    wave_ele_Val = []
    for i in np.linspace(0,T*n_w,1000):
        wave_ele_Val.append(wave_elevation(x, i))
    ax[j].plot(np.linspace(0,T*n_w,1000),wave_ele_Val)
    ax[j].grid()
    ax[j].set_title("Wave Elevation-Time Variations @ " + str(x) + "WaveLengths")
    ax[j].set_ylabel("\u03B7")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.show()
```

This gives me:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I got all 5 on one page but the lines aren't showing up. Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: It still dosn't work. it says:  TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I'm a bit cueless, because for me, it's working just fine... (see picture)